# magento category loop not showing important product information

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to organize the category page by dividing the products into subcategories. When I loop through the subcategories (on catalog\product\list.phtml) with the code:

$child_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($child_id);
$_productCollection =  Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addCategoryFilter($child_cat);

and then proceed to loop through the products...

foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):

It does not seem to differentiate between products that are set to be visible and products that are not (both are shown). It also does not show images, prices, or any other information. The only correct information I get is the product URL.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, when you load a product collection you'll get a bare amount of information about the products.  Ex:

```
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 9
    [entity_type_id] => 4
    [attribute_set_id] => 4
    [type_id] => simple
    [sku] => DLKJFER343
    [has_options] => 0
    [required_options] => 0
    [created_at] => 2012-12-07 16:04:58
    [updated_at] => 2012-12-11 16:21:37
    [cat_index_position] => 0
    [stock_item (Varien_Object)] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

You need to explicitly tell Magento to load extra information or to filter by a value like this:

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel( 'catalog/product_collection' );
// Filter by enabled products
$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter( 'status', 1 );
// Load all product information
$_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect( '*' );
$_productCollection->addCategoryFilter( $category );
```

Now you'll see something like this (using `$_product->debug()` to dump out some information):

```
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 3
    [entity_type_id] => 4
    [attribute_set_id] => 4
    [type_id] => simple
    [sku] => DLKJFER343
    [has_options] => 0
    [required_options] => 0
    [created_at] => 2012-12-05 18:47:39
    [updated_at] => 2012-12-11 16:20:25
    [cat_index_position] => 0
    [status] => 1
    [visibility] => 4
    [enable_googlecheckout] => 1
    [tax_class_id] => 2
    [is_recurring] => 0
    [weight] => 3.0000
    [price] => 534.2500
    [name] => Sample Product
    [url_key] => some-product
    [is_returnable] => 2
    [msrp_enabled] => 2
    [msrp_display_actual_price_type] => 4
    [image] => /w/r/something.png
    [small_image] => /w/r/something_sm.png
    [thumbnail] => /w/r/something_th.png
    [options_container] => container2
    [url_path] => some-product.html
    [image_label] => One image label
    [small_image_label] => Another image label
    [thumbnail_label] => An image label
    [description] => Long winded blah, blah, blah.
    [short_description] => Blah, blah, blah.
    [stock_item (Varien_Object)] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

The media gallery information (labels, etc) is a different beast and must be specifically requested through the `getMediaGalleryImages()` method of the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` object.

**HOWEVER** this method will return `NULL` if called while looping through a product collection.  Oddly, you cannot access this data without explicitly loading the product model (for reasons I won't go into in this response).  So, we need to try something like this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/product' )->load( $_product->getId() );
$images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
```

There's [a performance hit](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/29639/) doing this in your collection loop though, so be careful.

---

EDIT:

Mage_Catalog_Block_Product->getLoadedProductCollection()

Long, long, **long** story short (this method digs deep)... as far as I can tell  `getLoadedProductCollection()` will only show attributes which have `Used In Product Listing` set to `Yes`.

[image]

The reason resides in Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Config...

```
public function getAttributesUsedInListing()
{
        // ... some code above omitted...
        ->where('main_table.entity_type_id = ?', (int)$this->getEntityTypeId())
        // THIS RIGHT HERE IS WHY
        ->where('additional_table.used_in_product_listing = ?', 1);

    return $adapter->fetchAll($select);
}
```

Comment: wow - thanks for the detailed response. You warned about a performance hit - I am very worried about this. All the product information is loaded at the beginning of the page through **$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();** Currently I am grabbing the subcategories and trying to get another full info load of the products (the question you have answered here). This seems repetative - is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: The performance hit comes from (technically) re-loading/querying each product model inside your foreach loop.  Not ideal.  The short answer is: it depends on your setup.  Use the `->debug()` method of the product model to see what's available to you when you're simply iterating through the product collection.  See what's in there that you have available to you and slowly add the fields you need through `addAttributeToSelect`.  It looks like the image gallery basic information is included when you specify `addAttributeToSelect( 'images' )` so you might be good to go.

Comment: I will look into it - thank you so much for your time and knwoledge - you were a huge help to me!

Comment: Ahh, I just noticed `$this->getLoadedProductCollection()` ... yeah, that's a fun one.  You cannot modify that outside of over-riding the method in some custom code but, IIRC, it gets to be a little bit of a pain.  I'll get into it below.